# How to create box colliders in Unity that allow four objects to disappear once 4 objects are colliding and one new object to appear in the middle

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, vuforia

I am very new to Unity and Vuforia and I have a study assignment to solve. I want to create 4 objects(Vuforia) in a scene that when they collide the four objects disappear and one fifth object appears augmented in the middle and when they disperse the 4 objects reappear. Any help would be very much appreciated. Please note that I don't know how to code in Unity. Please explain step by step to achieve the desired result. Thanks loads in advance.

I got some help setting the scene but the objects are not augmenting properly, they look like they drift away from the markers.

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProtoTypeV : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectOne, objectTwo, objectThree, mainObject;

```
public bool oneCollision, twoCollision, threeCollision;


public void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (oneCollision && twoCollision && threeCollision)
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
        objectOne.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
        objectTwo.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
        objectThree.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;

        mainObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("tracking");
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        objectOne.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        objectTwo.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        objectThree.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;

        mainObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "ObjectOne")
    {
        oneCollision = true;
    }
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "ObjectTwo")
    {
        twoCollision = true;
    }
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ObjectThree")
    {
        threeCollision = true;
    }
}

public void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ObjectOne")
    {
        oneCollision = false;  
    }
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "ObjectTwo")
    {
        twoCollision = false;
    }
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "ObjectThree")
    {
        threeCollision = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you trying with 4 image targets or just 1 image target to make your 4 objects appear?

Comment: @Saif I have created 4 images target for each of the four objects. The appearance of the 4 AR objects is a bit glitchy and is not showing properly. Also when they collide, the fifth object appear but then stays on the screen even if I physically separate the markers.

Comment: @Saif Could you please help me to start with new file by guiding me step by step on how to do it? I also created some 3D objects and imported them to Unity but they are not working. is there any specific format other then .obj

Comment: 3D objects that you have imported may be of different scale. You need to reduce them to a minimal size so that it is visible in camera view.

Comment: I am assuming that the 5th object is not tracked. If you have a video of how you are doing this maybe it can help.

Comment: @Saif I have scaled down the 3D object but didn't work. I used simple 3D objects inside unity (cube, sphere...) and it worked. I don't have the file with me now to send you any snaps. can u please help to direct me to the right code to accomplish the result I want? many thanks

Comment: @Saif just to quickly illustrate what I am trying to do. so i have four pieces of puzzle and each has one object displaying in AR at the same time. When these objects collide (touch or in AR), they disappear and I want a fifth object to appear in the middle (not tracked) and when they separate, the object in the middle disappear and they reappear, does it make sense now?

Comment: First try your logic with simple shape objects. Once that is done, then you can replace them with 3D objects. (use small objects only). Also, record a video of what is exactly happening so that we can guide you from that position. Please post codes here too.

Comment: Since 5th object is anyway appearing. Find the distance between 5th object and any one of the 4 objects. If the distance is more than a value then disappear 5th object and reappear other 4 objects. Instead of turning objects completely off, you can just switch between mesh renderer option.

Comment: @Saif thanks very much for your feedback. I can show u a small video and code tomorrow or Monday when I go back to school. If thats okay, in this case you can guide me better to accomplish the result I need. thanks again and talk  to you soon

Comment: @Saif I will add the code in my question above. Please have a look and advise.